# AngularJS View Showing {} Instead of $scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My view is outputting {} instead of the desired $scope value. See code below:

app.js:

```
angular
  .module('tbsmapApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngRoute',
    'firebase'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/country/:country', {
        templateUrl: 'views/country.html',
        controller: 'CountryCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'country'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

country.js:

```
angular.module('tbsmapApp')
  .controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $firebaseObject, FirebaseRef, $routeParams) {
                 $scope.country = $routeParams.country;
  });
```

The view:

```
<h1>Top Sites by Traffic in <span>{{country}}</span></h1>
```

Any idea why this is happening? I am running jVectorMap in the application. That wouldn't have anything to do with it - would it?

Comment: post your full view code.

Comment: show me your url when it  access 'country' state

Comment: put in controller > [var country= this; country.country = $routeParams.country;] in your view set [ {{country.country}} ]

Comment: i think that because in the route configs you set "controllerAs", remove it or try above code and check it again.

Comment: Whatever it is will show in browser console...did you even look there? And you are defintiely mixing controllerAs and $scope...pick one or the other